# Error installing symfony CMF

Tags: symfony, symfony-cmf

I am trying to get symfony cmf up and running. After encountering a few problems during install, i'm stuck at this error message:

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Cmf\Component\Routing\ContentAwareGenerator::getBestLocaleRoute() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Routing\Route, instance of Doctrine\ODM\PHPCR\Document\Generic given, called in D:\wamp\www\QHCMF\vendor\symfony-cmf\routing\Symfony\Cmf\Component\Routing\ContentAwareGenerator.php on line 86 and defined in D:\wamp\www\QHCMF\vendor\symfony-cmf\routing\Symfony\Cmf\Component\Routing\ContentAwareGenerator.php on line 98
```

I'm a novice and I have no clue what to make of this. I have looked at the ContentAwareGenerator.php but it was of no help to me.

Comment: Others might know the answer if you would provide more info. What operating system do you use? Are you installing using composer, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a Generic document when no specific document is at that position in the content repository. PHPCR being a tree, there sometimes are nodes added in between so that a child node can have a parent. Those nodes do not map to any document, in which case the Generic document is used.

If you simply installed the sandbox from git and followed all the steps in order, this should not happen. You first set up the repository, then load the fixtures. If this is what you did, please open an issue at https://github.com/symfony-cmf/cmf-sandbox

Comment: I installed the standard edition, I will try to install the sandbox edition and see if the problem persists.